# Add product/downloadable option to individual product variants

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a bunch of downloadable products in the shop, all of which have different variants. One of those is a trial version for the product, which I'd like to be able to flag accordingly.
When setting up the different variants, it's possible to set "downloadable", "virtual", etc. for each of the variants individually in WooCommerce.
What I would like to add, is another checkbox ([ ] Trial Version) within the variant itself and not the general product, but I can't find the right place to add this.

This is what I've tried after quite a while of trial&error:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'add_trialversion_product_option' );
function add_trialversion_product_option( $product_type_options ) 
{
    $product_type_options['trialversion'] = array(
        'id'            => '_trialversion',
        'wrapper_class' => 'show_if_variable',
        'label'         => __( 'Trial Version', 'woocommerce' ),
        'description'   => __( '', 'woocommerce' ),
        'default'       => 'no'
    );
    return $product_type_options;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_trialversion_option_fields'  );
function save_trialversion_option_fields( $post_id ) 
{
    $is_trialversion = isset( $_POST['_trialversion'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_trialversion', $is_trialversion );
}
```

While this adds the "Trial Version" checkbox to a variable product in general, this is not what I'm looking for as I want to set some variants of the product to be a trial version and some to be a regular version.

I hope I'm just missing something obvious, but since I'm not a woocommerce expert, I'm having some trouble finding it.

Thanks for any help :)

I've added an image here, just in case it's not clear where I'd like to add a checkbox:
[woocommerce screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MphO5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for each and add to where you want, since variation options are in a different place than where you're trying to filter.

```
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options', 'he_add_to_variation_option', 10, 3);
function he_add_to_variation_option( $loop, $variation_data, $variation){
    $is_trial = (get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_trialversion', true)) ? ' checked' : '';
    ?>
    <label class="tips" data-tip="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enable this option to make as a trial version', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Trial Version?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox variable_is_trial_version" name="_trialversion[<?php echo esc_attr( $variation->ID ); ?>]"<?php echo $is_trial;?>/>
    </label>
<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_trialversion_option_fields'  );
function save_trialversion_option_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['_trialversion'] ) ){
        foreach ( $_POST['_trialversion'] as $productid=>$checked ){
            update_post_meta( $productid, '_trialversion', 'yes' );
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: This works great, thank you very much. I'm now realizing another issue, but I'm not sure if this is a followup question or something completely different: The WordPress plugin "Germanized" has an option to display checkboxes during checkout with conditions. One of them is the type of digital download, but I'm unable to find the new "Trial Version" setting there. Is there another place where I have to configure this to make the "Trial Version" show up along with "Downloadable", "Virtual" etc.?

Comment: You can definitely add something to the checkout. What you're asking about sounds like another question for SO though.